# Getting started with Laradock on Mac

Tags: docker, laravel-5, docker-compose, laradock

I'm just getting started with learning Laravel, as well as taking my first dive into Docker. I've taken the time to understand what Docker is and (more or less) how it works, and have also set up Docker Native on my Mac (Sierra).

I'm following along with the documentation at: http://laradock.io/getting-started/, but am a bit confused on how to proceed. The current version of Laradock is v5 which has a different setup to previous versions. I'd like to maintain a different docker environment for each project, and as per the documentation:

> Follow these steps if you want a separate Docker environment for each project

So I proceeded with the section titled **A.2) Don’t have a PHP project yet**, where it mentions that the folder should look like:

```
+ laradock
+ project-z
```

So in my home directory I have a general Dev folder, and inside that I have a Laravel folder. So in `~/Dev/Laravel/` do I clone the Laradock git repo, and then alongside it (*it* being the `laradock` folder that is created) create my projects? So by my understanding I will therefore end up with:

```
~/Dev/Laravel/laradock
~/Dev/Laravel/project-1
~/Dev/Laravel/project-2
~/Dev/Laravel/project-...
```

If so, then this does not seem to be a separate Docker environment for each project.

Or should I instead go the route of creating a new empty Laravel project first and then clone the Laradock git repo into that?

I know this a very noobie question, but I'm unsure on how to proceed. **Any** help is humbly welcome!

Note: I have homebrew, composer and PHP7 already installed on my Mac.

Comment: Did you try to this docker image eboraas/laravel? https://hub.docker.com/r/eboraas/laravel/, Or try to see how to set up this framework?

Comment: Hi German. Thank you for the link. I haven't seen this before as I had heard so many good things about Laradock.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a separate Docker environment for each project, clone the Laradock repo **inside** each project directory. Your directory structure should look like:

```
+ project-a
  + laradock-a
+ project-b
  + laradock-b
```

Alternatively, if you want a single Docker environment for all your projects, your directory structure should look like:

```
+ laradock
+ project-1
+ project-2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to go with adding laradock as a **submodule** to an existing laravel app's folder with command: `git submodule add https://github.com/Laradock/laradock.git` first. 
You have to initialize Git first ofc to do that.

To be concrete, you need to see a folder structure like this:

[image]

Comment: Using laradock as a git submodule is a good practice, but is not related with the question the user is asking.